# C++ Binary Search Tree Level Order with Null Values

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print a tree in level order, but if the node is missing a child, I want to print null in its place. I wasn't sure if I needed if statements or pushing a null value into the queue might be the way to go.

```
/* Iterative program to print levels line by line */
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

// A Binary Tree Node
struct node
{
    struct node *left;
    int data;
    struct node *right;
};

// Iterative method to do level order traversal line by line
void printLevelOrder(node *root)
{
    // Base Case
    if (root == NULL)  return;

    // Create an empty queue for level order tarversal
    queue<node *> q;

    // Enqueue Root and initialize height
    q.push(root);

    while (1)
    {
        // nodeCount (queue size) indicates number of nodes
        // at current lelvel.
        int nodeCount = q.size();
        if (nodeCount == 0)
            break;

        // Dequeue all nodes of current level and Enqueue all
        // nodes of next level
        while (nodeCount > 0)
        {
            node *node = q.front();
            cout << node->data << " ";
            q.pop();
            if (node->left != NULL)
                q.push(node->left);
            if (node->right != NULL)
                q.push(node->right);
            nodeCount--;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

// Utility function to create a new tree node
node* newNode(int data)
{
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

Current Output:

```
    1 
   / \
  2   3
 /   / \
4   5   6
```

Prints the Binary Search Tree without any null values.

Intended Output:

```
                    1 
         /                   \
        2                     3
     /     \               /      \
    4       null         5        6
   / \                 /  \      /  \
null nul             null null null null
```

Prints Binary tree with the null values.

Any guidance towards the implementation of the null values would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just remove the checks for `node->left != NULL` and `node->right != NULL` so that you enqueue null children too. And make sure to check that `node` is not null before attempting to print `cout << node->data << " ";` and before attempting to enqueue `node`'s children (you don't wanna dereference a null pointer in either case).

Comment: if (node->left != NULL) ... else std::cout<<"null"; ?

Comment: @138 You wouldn't want to print at that moment though, otherwise you may break the level-order printing you're going for. For example, if you were on node 4 in OP's example, your change would print 4's children first, and then move on to print 4's siblings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print `NULL` children, just make sure they will be pushed into your queue since your queue **holds all the elements that will be printed**.

```
while (nodeCount > 0)
{
    node *node = q.front();
    q.pop();

    if (!node) {
        cout << "null" << " ";
    } else {
        cout << node->data << " ";
        q.push(node->left);
        q.push(node->right);
    }

    nodeCount--;
}
```